# proving a series is bounded on $n∈\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

In my calc book there's a question I don't understand.
Note: I still can't use derivatives, I am in the start of a calculus book

to prove that the following series

$\frac{n^5}{2^n}$
is bounded on $n∈\mathbb{N}$ (also need to find the bounders)
I can see that 2^x is bounded by 0 but I don't know if the division of both these functions adds another bounder, the main problem is finding a second bounder if it exists

I have tried setting an $M$ and $m$ s.t $\frac{n^5}{2^n}\ge m$ and $\frac{n^5}{2^n}\le M$ but don't know how to solve the inequality because moving the $2^n$ doesnt seem to help
It only seems that induction helps here but how do I choose an n so that the function is smaller or bigger then it without checking values from the function

Comment: Do you mean sequence ? or sum ?

Answer (score 0):

One way how to find an upper bound, in fact, the maximum of the sequence is to look at the sequence as the values $f(n)$ of the function $f(x):=x^52^{-x}$ defined for real $x$ (of course, for our purposes it suffices to consider positive real numbers). To find an extremum, we look for the points of zero derivative, ie. we look for $x$ such that $$f'(x)=5x^42^{-x}-x^52^{-x}\log2=x^42^{-x}(5-x\log2)=0$$ where $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm. We get $x=5/\log2 \approx 7.2$ and we also know that the function $f$ attains its maximum at this point - this is obvious from the fact that its derivative is positive on the left and negative on the right of this point.

Thus to answer the original question, it is sufficient to compute and compare $f(7)=7^5/2^7=131.3046875$ and $f(8)=8^5/2^8=128$. We see that as an upper bound we can take $f(7)$ or, say, nicer looking number $132$. As already mentioned in the comments, $0$ is a trivial lower bound.